# Python - Program wont recognize values in variable

Tags: python, pyautogui

I see nothing wrong with this, however it wont execute the last part of this program. I can put up the picture that it needs to recognise but it won't do anything. It's supposed to hold f for a certain amount of time once a certain picture pops up but the program needs to be enabled/disabled.

```
#Import all python librabries

global stat
stat = 0

def Main_window():
    #Create window object
    window=Tk()

    #program status

    li=Label(window, text="SRA Version 1")
    li.grid(row=0, column=0)

    li=Label(window, text="text")
    li.grid(row=0, column=2)

    #status
    li=Label(window, text="Disabled")
    li.grid(row=1, column=1)

    li=Label(window, text="text")
    li.grid(row=3, column=0)

    li=Label(window, text="text")
    li.grid(row=3, column=1)

    li=Label(window, text="txt")
    li.grid(row=4, column=1)

    li=Label(window, text="txt")
    li.grid(row=5, column=1)

    li=Label(window, text="Status: ")
    li.grid(row=6, column=0)

    li=Label(window, text="Alive")
    li.grid(row=6, column=1)
    #Button to activat
    def ChangeStatus1():
        li=Label(window, text="Enabled")
        li.grid(row=1, column=1)
        stat = 1

    def ChangeStatus2():
        li=Label(window, text="Disabled")
        li.grid(row=1, column=1)
        stat = 0

    statbutton = Button(window, text="Enable", command=ChangeStatus1)
    statbutton.grid(row=2, column=0)
    statbutton = Button(window, text="Disable", command=ChangeStatus2)
    statbutton.grid(row=2, column=2)
    #entry's
    if stat == 1:
        if pyautogui.locateOnScreen('img.png'):
            li=Label(window, text="txt")
            li.grid(row=6, column=1)
            keyboard = Controller()
            key = "f"

            keyboard.press(key)
            time.sleep(8)
            keyboard.release(key)
        else:
            li=Label(window, text="Alive")
            li.grid(row=6, column=1)
            
    window.mainloop()
Main_window()
```

Comment: Your tkinter windows etc won't start until after you have done the keyboard press/sleep/release thing. Also, once that has finished, it will never retry that bit again.

Comment: How can I try to fix this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you need quite a complex state machine to cover all the possibilities. I have added `def states():` to handle them:

```
#Import all python librabries

stat = 0

# global req   # 0=>nop 1=>active 2=>passive
req = 0

def Main_window():
    #Create window object
    window=Tk()

    #program status

    li=Label(window, text="SRA Version 1")
    li.grid(row=0, column=0)

    li=Label(window, text="text")
    li.grid(row=0, column=2)

    #status
    li=Label(window, text="Disabled")
    li.grid(row=1, column=1)

    li=Label(window, text="text")
    li.grid(row=3, column=0)

    li=Label(window, text="text")
    li.grid(row=3, column=1)

    li=Label(window, text="txt")
    li.grid(row=4, column=1)

    li=Label(window, text="txt")
    li.grid(row=5, column=1)

    li=Label(window, text="Status: ")
    li.grid(row=6, column=0)

    li=Label(window, text="Alive")
    li.grid(row=6, column=1)
    #Button to activat
    def ChangeStatus1():
        global req
        li=Label(window, text="Enabled")
        li.grid(row=1, column=1)
        req = 1
        states()

    def ChangeStatus2():
        global req
        li=Label(window, text="Disabled")
        li.grid(row=1, column=1)
        req = 2
        states()

    statbutton = Button(window, text="Enable", command=ChangeStatus1)
    statbutton.grid(row=2, column=0)
    statbutton = Button(window, text="Disable", command=ChangeStatus2)
    statbutton.grid(row=2, column=2)

    #entry's
    def states():
        global stat
        global req
        local_req = req
        req = 0
        if stat == 0:
            if local_req != 1:
               return
            stat = 1
        if stat == 1:
            if local_req == 2:
                stat = 0
                return
            if pyautogui.locateOnScreen('img.png'):
                stat = 2
                li=Label(window, text="txt")
                li.grid(row=6, column=1)
                keyboard = Controller()
    
                keyboard.press('f')
                window.after(8000, states)
            else:
                window.after(100, states)
        elif stat == 2:
            keyboard = Controller()
            keyboard.release('f')
            if local_req == 2:
               stat = 0
               return
            stat = 3
            window.after(100, states)
        elif stat == 3:
            if local_req == 2:
               stat = 0
               return
            if not pyautogui.locateOnScreen('img.png'):
                stat = 1
                li=Label(window, text="Alive")
                li.grid(row=6, column=1)
    
            window.after(100, states)

            
    window.mainloop()
Main_window()
```

Comment: This results in an error: `in states
    local_req = req
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'req' referenced before assignment`

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not used to using global variables.

Comment: @quanrana, I've never worked with States before but when it recognizes the image it doesnt hold F down. Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: Well it calls `keyboard.press('f')`. Is that not right?

Comment: yeah, it is supposed to hold f down for 8 seconds

Comment: Well, I use `window.after(8000, states)` to make `tkinter` call the `states()` function again after 8 seconds.

Comment: Well, why doesnt it hold f then? I'm confused.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226940/discussion-between-mark-dg-and-quamrana).

Answer (score 0):

I think you might want to put the `stat` variable check in the main loop. From what I can tell from the provided code, you're only checking if `stat == 1` once before you start the main window loop, meaning it never checks whenever you are clicking the buttons. The function changing `stat` to `1` also seems to be overwritten. `statbutton = Button(window, text="Enable", command=ChangeStatus1)` is created, but then later set  to `statbutton = Button(window, text="Disable", command=ChangeStatus2)`, leaving stat at 0. Maybe try renaming this second `statbutton` to something else. Though I'm not familiar with the libraries you're using, so these might not be an issue.

Comment: Statbutton can be left like how it is at the moment, I'll try your other suggestions out right now.